# LazyColumn is not keeping the state of items when scrolling

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Following the `Pathway` code labs from Google about Jetpack compose, I was trying out this code

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.animation.animateColorAsState
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.ButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.material.Divider
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.codelab.basics.ui.BasicsCodelabTheme

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContent {
           MyApp {
               MyScreenContent()
           }
       }
   }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
   BasicsCodelabTheme {
       Surface(color = Color.Yellow) {
           content()
       }
   }
}

@Composable
fun MyScreenContent(names: List<String> = List(1000) { "Hello Android #$it" }) {
   val counterState = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

   Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
       NameList(names, Modifier.weight(1f))
       Counter(
           count = counterState.value,
           updateCount = { newCount ->
               counterState.value = newCount
           }
       )
   }
}

@Composable
fun NameList(names: List<String>, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
   LazyColumn(modifier = modifier) {
       items(items = names) { name ->
           Greeting(name = name)
           Divider(color = Color.Black)
       }
   }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
   var isSelected by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
   val backgroundColor by animateColorAsState(if (isSelected) Color.Red else Color.Transparent)

   Text(
       text = "Hello $name!",
       modifier = Modifier
           .padding(24.dp)
           .background(color = backgroundColor)
           .clickable(onClick = { isSelected = !isSelected })
   )
}

@Composable
fun Counter(count: Int, updateCount: (Int) -> Unit) {
   Button(
       onClick = { updateCount(count + 1) },
       colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
           backgroundColor = if (count > 5) Color.Green else Color.White
       )
   ) {
       Text("I've been clicked $count times")
   }
}

@Preview("MyScreen preview")
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
   MyApp {
       MyScreenContent()
   }
}
```

I have noticed that `LazyColumn` will recompose the items whenever they become **Visible** on the screen (intended behaviour!) however, the Local state of `Greeting` widget is completely lost!

I believe this is a bug in Compose, Ideally the composer should consider the `remember` cached state. Is there an elegant way to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "the Local state of Greeting widget is completely lost" -- I am assuming that you mean `isSelected` and/or `backgroundColor`. "I believe this is a bug in Compose" -- I doubt it. `remember()` remembers for an individual composition (i.e., a particular invocation of a composable), until that composition is disposed. The point behind "`Lazy`" is that those compositions are not retained as they get scrolled well out of view, to minimize memory consumption. "Is there an elegant way to fix this?" -- hoist the state out of `Greeting()`, presumably. Or, use `Column()` and pay the memory price.

Comment: `remember() remembers for an individual composition (i.e., a particular invocation of a composable), until that composition is disposed.` This seems to be the answer to my wonder! Thanks a lot. I think `hoisting` the state to the caller scope is `the elegant` way. I will post my code in few! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**[Update]**

Using `rememberSaveable {...}` gives the power to survive the android change of configuration as well as the `scrollability`

**Docs**

```
Remember the value produced by init.
It behaves similarly to remember, but the stored value will survive the activity or process recreation using the saved instance state mechanism (for example it happens when the screen is rotated in the Android application).
```

The code now is more elegant and shorter, we don't even need to **hoist** the state, it can be kept internal. The only thing I am not so sure of now with using `rememberSaveable` is if there will be any performance penalties when the list grows bigger and bigger, say **1000** items.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    val isSelected = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val backgroundColor by animateColorAsState(if (isSelected.value) Color.Red else Color.Transparent)

    Text(
        text = "Hello $name! selected: ${isSelected.value}",
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(24.dp)
            .background(color = backgroundColor)
            .clickable(onClick = {
                isSelected.value = !isSelected.value
            })
    )
}
```

**[Original Answer]**

Based on [@CommonWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)'s answer The `LazyColumn` will dispose the composables along with their states when they are **off-screen** this means when `LazyColumn` recomposes the `Compsoables` again it will have fresh start `state`. To fix this issue all that has to be done is to **hoist** the state to the consumer's scope, `LazyColumn` in this case.

Also we need to use `mutableStateMapOf()` instead of `MutableMapOf` inside the `remember { ... }` lambda or Compose-core engine will not be aware of this change.

So far here is the code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun NameList(names: List<String>, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    val selectedStates = remember {
        mutableStateMapOf<Int, Boolean>().apply {
            names.mapIndexed { index, _ ->
                index to false
            }.toMap().also {
                putAll(it)
            }
        }
    }

    LazyColumn(modifier = modifier) {
        itemsIndexed(items = names) { index, name ->
            Greeting(
                name = name,
                isSelected = selectedStates[index] == true,
                onSelected = {
                    selectedStates[index] = !it
                }
            )
            Divider(color = Color.Black)
        }
    }
}
```

Happy composing!

Comment: `rememberSaveable` is an interesting solution. Would be really interesting to know how that performs in large lists as you said.

Comment: @Aouledissa, this part `selectedStates[index] = !it` is confusing