# Selected Item loosing state in LazyVerticalGrid in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am having a Grid list in my app where I am changing background color on card click. It seems to work fine until I scroll. I know compose will redraw the hidden element when the hidden item becomes visible again. I am having issue is managing state of my list items.

[image: Snapshot]

```
data class MonthFee(var isPaid :Boolean,var month :String,var monthIndex :Long)


@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun MonthSelectList2(
monthList: List<MonthFee>,
color: Color,
onMonthSelect: (list: List<MonthFee>) -> Unit) {

val selectedItems = remember { mutableStateListOf<MonthFee>() }

LazyVerticalGrid(
    userScrollEnabled = true,
    modifier = Modifier.background(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background.copy(0.6f)),
    columns = GridCells.Adaptive(150.dp)
) {
    items(items = monthList,key = {it.monthIndex}) { item ->

        val isSelected = selectedItems.contains(item)
        val cardBgColor = remember { 
          mutableStateOf(item.isPaid.getActivatedColor(color))
        }

        Card(backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.background.copy(1f),
            onClick = {

                if (!item.isPaid) {
                    if (isSelected) {
                        selectedItems.remove(item)
                        cardBgColor.value = Color.LightGray
                    } else {
                        selectedItems.add(item)
                        cardBgColor.value = color.copy(0.65f)
                    }
                    onMonthSelect(selectedItems.toList())
                }

            }) {
            Box{
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.background(color = cardBgColor.value)
                ) {
                    Text(text = item.month)
                }
                if (item.isPaid) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.green_tick),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .requiredSize(25.dp)
                            .padding(start = 0.dp, end = 0.dp, top = 0.dp, bottom =0.dp)
                            .clip(CircleShape),
                        contentDescription = ""
                    )
                }
            }}}}}
```

Extension Used Above

```
fun Boolean.getActivatedColor(color: Color): Color {
return if (this) {
    color
} else {
    Color.LightGray
}}
```

I have tried hoisting the state, used rememberSaveable{} but the UI is not persistent on scroll. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66516702/lazycolumn-is-not-keeping-the-state-of-items-when-scrolling)

Comment: You are suppose to save itemState with your Data Class. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77852780/checkbox-state-is-not-changing-in-jetpack-compose-lazycolumn-items/77854179#77854179

Answer (score 0):

**To persist your card state even the item is scrolled off-screen. You need to:**

- Creates a list of Boolean values, all set to false, with the number of elements equal to your list `monthList.size`.

```
val selectedItems = remember {
    mutableStateListOf<Boolean>().apply {
        addAll(List(monthList.size) { false })
    }
}
```

- Use `itemsIndexed` instead of `items` to get the boolean value for the appropriate list index.

```
itemsIndexed(selectedItems) { index, isSelected ->
    YourLayout(
        isSelected = isSelected,
        onSelectedChanged = {
            selectedItems[index] = isSelected
        }
    )
}
```

- And in your`YourLayout` you declare a `remember` variable to keep track of the change boolean values.

```
 var selected by remember {
     mutableStateOf(isSelected)
 }
 LaunchedEffect(key1 = isSelected) {
     onSelectedChanged(isSelected)
 }
```

**Here is all you code example:**

```
    @Composable
    fun MonthSelectList2(
        monthList: List<MonthFee>,
        color: Color,
        onMonthSelect: (list: List<MonthFee>) -> Unit
    ) {
        val selectedItems = remember {
            mutableStateListOf<Boolean>().apply {
                addAll(List(monthList.size) { false })
            }
        }

        LazyVerticalGrid(
            userScrollEnabled = true,
            modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Black),
            columns = GridCells.Adaptive(150.dp)
        ) {

            itemsIndexed(selectedItems) { index, isSelected ->
                YourLayout(
                    isSelected = isSelected,
                    onSelectedChanged = {
                        selectedItems[index] = isSelected
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun YourLayout(
    isSelected: Boolean,
    onSelectedChanged: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    var selected by remember {
        mutableStateOf(isSelected)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = isSelected) {
        onSelectedChanged(isSelected)
    }

    // Card....
}
```